# (PHP) Replacing a string with an array value

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have a regular expression that finds the text in between two square brackets:

```
preg_match_all("/(?<=\[).+?(?=\])/", $body, $matches);
```

From an array called `row` I need to get the value at the key that was matched from the regex and replace it in the `$body` string.

For example,

```
foreach ($matches[0] as $array_key) {
    row->$array_key;
    //The value at the specific key, but I need to take this value and put it back in the spot where its key was found in the body string

}
```

Comment: Any example string and expected output? The question sounds unclear. Looks like you are looking for `preg_repace`

Comment: Is there any more code?

Comment: `row->$array_key;` looks like you are working with object, not with array. Show exemplary input contents for `$body` and `row`

Comment: _Some guys ask and escape. Look, it's not a conventional forum, it's StackOverflow._

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$body = '[testtext][othertext]';
preg_match_all("/(?<=\[).+?(?=\])/", $body, $matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $key => $value)
{
    $values[] = $value;
}
print_r($values);
```

Result is:

```
Array ( [0] => testtext [1] => othertext )
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me

```
 <pre>
    <?php 
     $b = "Name: some sample text [] and some other [] and the thired one [] and 4 [] putting it on end[] and some thing after";
     preg_match_all("/(?<=\[).+?(?=\])/", $b, $m);

     $str = substr($b, 0,strpos($b, '[')+1);

     $row= array("val1","val2","val3","val4","val5");

     foreach($row as $k => $value) {

        $afterstr =  (  $k <=  count($m[0])-1 ) ?  $m[0][$k] : ""; // because the last ']' is not in $m array so we have to handle that
        $str .= $value . $afterstr ;
    }

    $str .= strrchr($b,']'); // appending after the last ']' text
    var_dump($str);
```

**string(135) "Name: some sample text [val1] and some other [val2] and the thired one [val3] and 4 [val4] putting it on end[val5] and some thing after**